# Fresh install of 12.04 Kernel panic

Tags: 12.04, kernel, init, kill

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer. After the Ubuntu splash screen, the computer throws up this error:

```
sr 2:0:1:0: [sr0] Unhandled error code
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
PID: 1, comm: run-init Not Tainted 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu
```

The computer hardware is as follows: Core 2 quad 9400, 8gb RAM, GTX 275, 3 Mech HD, 2 SSD, Win 7 install.

I would like to dual boot Ubuntu on this computer if possible. I did try placing this disk in my laptop and booted successfully which leads me to believe the fault lies with the desktop. Under windows all hardware seems to work ok. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert and just an average user, but in the past I had success running a **newer** or **older** kernel version than the one causing the problem.

Comment: You may want to expand this answer by editing it to explain *how* to do this.